# Set a value of a specific column for each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix `A` with `m` rows and I'd like to set a specific element of each row equal 1. The column index varies from row to row and is specified by a column vector `a` (with `m` values). That is, I want `A_{i,a_i} = 1`. Is there a quick way to do this in Matlab (without a for-loop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it using the [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), 1:numel(a), a')) = 1
```

Comment: That is indeed the way to do it